# React class component, data being initialized as undefined and then populated. unable to map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing an application using react class components. Below is my component. Data is fetched asynchronously from an API endpoint.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
...etc etc
import { doGetCompilation } from '../controllers/compilationController';

class Forms extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            step: 1,
        };
        this.getCompilation = this.getCompilation.bind(this);
    }

    state = {
        step: 1,
        compilation: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        this.getCompilation();
    }

    async getCompilation() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        try {
            let data = await doGetCompilation('ceb9baad7baefeb4d9d94cae8082452f53563baf');
            this.setState({ isLoading: false, compilation: data.data });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    render() {

        const {
            step,
            compilation,
            isLoading,
        } = this.state;

        console.log('compilation', compilation);

        return (
            <>
                {isLoading ? (
                    <div>Loading...</div>
                ) : (compilation && Array.isArray(compilation.steps) &&
                    compilation.steps.map((step, index) => (
                        <Paper variant="outlined" sx={{ my: { xs: 3, md: 6 }, p: { xs: 2, md: 3 } }}>
                            <Stepper
                                steps={step}
                                activeStep={0}
                            />

                            <Form/>
                        </Paper >
                    )))
                }
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Forms;
```

I'm getting an error while mapping over my compilation object. This object is undefined initially and then it is populated on componentDidMount. But this is not something react seem to like. In fact no matter what i can not render my component. Can you suggest a solution or an interesting article to read about this behaviour.
The error i get is :

Forms.jsx:81 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

object:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "token": "ceb9baad7baefeb4d9d94cae8082452f53563baf",
        "form": {
            "id": 17,
            "name": "aziende"
        },
        "steps": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "STEP 2 - Informazioni lavorative",
                "weight": null,
                "questions": []
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "STEP 2 - Informazioni personali",
                "weight": null,
                "questions": []
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "STEP 1 - Informazioni preliminari",
                "weight": null,
                "questions": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: `compilation.steps?.map`

Comment: *"I'm getting an error"* - What is the error?  What operation produces the error?  What are the runtime values used in that operation?  Are they what you expect them to be?

Comment: no, I tried this as well as soon as i found the problem but didnt' help

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'steps') @David

Answer (score 0):

try to put the         `compilation: []` inside the state in the constructor

Comment: thanks but its not working:      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            step: 1,
            compilation: [],
        };
        this.getCompilation = this.getCompilation.bind(this);
    }

Comment: it seems also that you need 2 nested maps 

the first for compilations and the other is for each compilation steps, because the response is returning an array or you can use the compilation[0].steps.map((step, index) if the api is for getting 1 value only (backend response in that we should be non array)

Comment: i believe you are right. im gonna try this .. meanwhile thanks

Comment: @MirkoNardi please check my code modification for a quick solution

Comment: tested and working shadi1999. that's why its not good coding at night sometimes :-)

Comment: @MirkoNardi  haha! it happens dear.